# Android nullpointer in chromecast sender sample

Tags: android, chromecast

Ive run through all the steps in the basic set up of the chromecast sender app at https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender?hl=ko

I keep getting a nullpointer in my onCreateOptions menu here:

```
MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = 
            (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
            mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(this.mediaRouteSelector);
```

When I debug and step through i can see that the mActionProvider in the menu item is null.

However I set up the menu exactly like it is in the sample using

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
>
<item
    android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
```

heres my instantiating of the mediarouter in my oncreate

```
mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                mediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
                    .addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID))
                .build();
```

Im also using an activity that extends from ActionBarActivity and Ive import all the libraries needed. Ive seen this is a common problem but I havent seen a common fix yet. Is there some new flag or something Im missing to get this working?

Comment: Have you got the Google Play Service dependency in your Android manifest:
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: lol my source control must've removed that from my manifest because I just looked and it wasnt there. Im rebuilding now.

Comment: well that didnt help. Ive added it to the manifest but I still get the nullpointer on setRouteSelector

Comment: If it is a NPE, you should be able to track it down and see what is null and fix your code. You can also look at the Android samples that we have on GitHub to see how they are doing it; the code snippets in documentations are just snippets and they may lack some required supporting codes

Comment: @AliNaddaf I finally got it working. All I had to do was add a MediaRouter.Callback. Also I just do a null check on my mediaRouteActionProvider and if its null I create a new one with the current context on the fly and then using the MenuItemCompat I set the new action to the menuitem. That way no matter what I never have a null menuitem.mActionProvider causing me an npe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To any one looking up a similar npe as the one I was getting here is the solution that fixed my problem. I was running into a null pointer here:

```
MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = 
(MediaRouteActionProvider)  MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
```

When I did some debugging I could see that even though all my set up was correct that for some reason in my project something was causing the action provider of the menuitem to always be null. My solution which works for me was to just set one on the fly and then I was able to finally get the device popup to show with the following code.

```
MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = 
(MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);

if(mediaRouteActionProvider==null){

   mediaRouteActionProvider  = new  MediaRouteActionProvider(this);
   MenuItemCompat.setActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem, mediaRouteActionProvider);

}

mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(this.mediaRouteSelector);
mediaRouteActionProvider.setDialogFactory(new MediaRouteDialogFactory() {
    @Override
    public MediaRouteControllerDialogFragment onCreateControllerDialogFragment() {

           return new MediaRouteControllerDialogFragment() {

                   @Override
                   public MediaRouteControllerDialog onCreateControllerDialog(
                      Context context, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                      MediaRouteControllerDialog mControllerDialog = 
                      new MediaRouteControllerDialog(TrailerPlayer.this);
                      return mControllerDialog;

             }
                        };
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your menu is already inflated. If you are using custom Super class,add the addMediaRouterButton call after the menu was inflated.